# How to create a stacked barplot with two factors that both determine fill?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Here's the data that I'm working with.

```
structure(list(NewRegion = c("Northeastern Atlantic", "Northeastern Atlantic", 
"Northeastern Atlantic", "Northeastern Atlantic", "Northeastern Atlantic", 
"Northeastern Atlantic", "Northeastern Atlantic", "Northeastern Atlantic", 
"Northeastern Atlantic", "Northeastern Atlantic", "Northeastern Atlantic", 
"Northeastern Atlantic"), New_categories = c("Behaviour", "Behaviour", 
"Environmental conditions", "Environmental conditions", "Habitat use", 
"Habitat use", "Interaction", "Invasive species", "Management", 
"Management", "Movement", "Movement"), New_Water = c("Fresh", 
"Marine", "Fresh", "Marine", "Fresh", "Marine", "Fresh", "Fresh", 
"Fresh", "Marine", "Fresh", "Marine"), count = c(12L, 17L, 10L, 
7L, 5L, 11L, 1L, 12L, 5L, 11L, 18L, 24L)), row.names = c(NA, 
12L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is my current plot code.

```
ggplot(EAtl, aes(x = New_categories, y = count, fill = New_categories, color = New_Water)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity', color = 'black')+ scale_fill_manual(values = colforplots)+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.01,0.01))+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent', colour = NA),
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent', colour = NA),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = 'black'),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(color = 'black'),
        legend.position = 'none', axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 19, face = 'bold'), axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

This barplot shows the counts for each category in the Northeastern Atlantic region. I have added a color argument to represent the New_Water category. However, this doesn't change any colors, only adds a line that splits each bar into two. I would like to maintain the color scheme, but have one section of each bar (say for freshwater) have texture (i.e. diagonal slashes) through it.

I found some older discussions on similar topics, but no concrete answers/updates.

Comment: the argument `color` means the color for the edges of bars, not meant to fill the color inside the bars, if you remove the argument `color=''black''` in `geom_bar`, you will see the difference. And it seems to me that you already have x-axis indicating categories, perhaps you don't need to fill different colors to emphasize it, my suggestion would be to `fill=New_water`. Here is the code I suggest at for the first two lines : `ggplot(EAtl, aes(x = New_categories, y = count, fill = New_Water)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity')+scale_fill_manual(values = colforplots) +...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things to note here that should help you out:

- You set the `color=` aesthetic in `ggplot()`, but then have it overwritten in `geom_bar()` by setting `color="black"`.  If you remove `color='black'`, you will now have colored boxes and a legend created based on "New_Water".  This still doesn't help you out too much, since it's hard to differentiate, but it's part of the issue here.
- Patterned fills are not supported directly in `ggplot`.  [You can look into a new package](https://coolbutuseless.github.io/2020/04/01/introducing-ggpattern-pattern-fills-for-ggplot/) called `ggpattern`, but I'm unable to install on my R version.  It seems `geom_col_patterned()` might help you out there.
- A simple solution that could work without `ggpattern` is to use the `alpha=` aesthetic to change the overall color intensity based on "New_Water".  This is especially useful here, since you only have two labels: Fresh and Marine water.  I'll show you an implementation of that below.

#### Solution using alpha aesthetic to simulate two "patterns"

To set the `alpha=` aesthetic, you can just change your `color=` to `alpha=` in the `ggplot()` line of your code.  The default variation of alpha does not look great; however, so I had to make a few changes in order for this to work out okay:

- Removed `theme(legend.position="none"` <- I want to see the legends now
- Set the color of your gridlines to a lighter gray so that it does not contrast too much with the transparent bars
- Used `scale_alpha_manual()` to select some reasonable values for both labels.

Here's the code:

```
ggplot(EAtl, aes(x = New_categories, y = count, fill = New_categories, alpha = New_Water)) +
      geom_bar(position = 'stack', stat = 'identity', color = 'black')+
      scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.8,0.4)) +
      scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.01,0.01))+
      theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent', colour = NA),
            plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'transparent', colour = NA),
            panel.grid.minor = element_line(color = 'gray80'),
            panel.grid.major = element_line(color = 'gray80'),
            axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
            axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
            axis.text.y = element_text(size = 19, face = 'bold'), axis.title.y = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: This should work perfectly! I didn't realize that the alpha argument could be included as an aesthetic!